# Sort an array with a pre-defined sort order

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pseudocode

I need to sort a k-sorted array recursively where the array is a set of "sort of" sorted values.

A k-sorted array is defined by the following equation A[i] <= A[i + k] for every i

An example of this would be the 
array {6, 1, 3, 7, 2, 4} 
and 
k = 3 
This is because A[0] <= A[3], A[1] <= A[4], A[2] <= A[3] 
where A[i] <= A[i + k]

How can I start to go about solving this problem? It needs to be done recursively and I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Hint: Treat all k-th items as a separate set (i.e. items 0, k, 2k, ..., items 1, k+1, 2k+1, ...), sort each set individually.

Comment: Can you elaborate? With regards to my example please? (I've been at this problem for 8 hours now and I'm burning out really fast)

If you mean treat it as {0, 0+k} {1, 1+k}
Or do you mean {0, k, 2k}, {1, k+1, 2k+1} how would that go about solving the sorting problem?
How would I go about merging them back together anyway?

Comment: The array you're given is equivalent to zipping k many arrays together, in your example the k=3 arrays are {6, 7}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}. Each of these sub-arrays is obtained by visiting the k-th element. Each sub-array is sorted within itself. First you need a function to sort a general array. Then modify this function to not consider every item in the array, but only every k-th item. Call this function k times with offsets 0..k-1

Comment: I know how to "stitch" them together literately, but how can I do this recursively? My professor's only hint was how to break a k = 4 sorted array into a k = 2 and so on.

Comment: Write a working iterative version first, then convert it into a recursive one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let call your array A, with k = k_original.

To do this recursively, you can break it in to 2 smaller arrays with 
their k =  k_original / 2.

For example : your k_original = 5, then break it into 2 arrays with k=3 and k=2.

- First with (k=3) by taking element : A[0], A[1], A[2], A[5], A[6], A[7], A[10], A[11], A[12], ... just take 3 elements and skip the next 2 (they are for the other small array), follow the problem's rule, A[0] < A[5], A[1] < A[6], ... so this small array satisfy (k=3)
- The rest of the element go in the second array (which is k=2 in this case), and they will also satisfy the rule for (k=2).

Keep breaking them down, if the after breaking, (k=1) then return the array, and you can be sure that it's already sorted.

Then with 2 smaller already sorted array, just [merge 2 sorted array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-sorted-arrays/) to combine them.

Here are my pseudo code :

```
function sortK (A, k) :
    if (k=1) return A;
    A_first_half = A[0 ~ k/2] + A[k ~ 3k/2] + A [2k ~ 5k/2] + ...
    A_second_half = A[k/2 ~ k] + A[3k/2 ~ 2k] + A[5k/2 ~ 3k] + ...
    sorted_first_half = sortK (A_first_half, k/2);
    sorted_second_half = sortK (A_second_half, k/2);
    return merge(A_first_half, A_second_half);
```

Note : you need to take care of case when k cannot divide by 2, but it's really not that hard, do it like my example.